# How can I derive block device information using the output of lsusb

Tags: usb, block-device, lsusb

I am building a script that will let the user select a USB disk as a backup target. The idea is to create a partition spanning the entire device. `lsusb` gives the vendor ID and name, which I intend to present to the user.

I obviously only want to list disks, no other devices. I also need to figure out the `/dev` device name of the disk that the user selects in order to create a partition on it. I have looked through `/dev/disk/` and `/sys/` trying to find cross references in the various symlinks there. I also have not been able to utilize `lsblk` and `df` to achieve my goal. I would like to know:

- How can I use the information that `lsusb` provides to figure out which USB devices are disks?
- How can I use the information that `lsusb` provides to get the `/dev` device name of a specific device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question depends somewhat on what mechanism will be used to trigger the script.

Assuming that the script is called from some kind of backup program which is not immediately called when the USB device is attached (as would be the case if you trigger it from a *udev* rule, for example), then you can use `udevadm info` to gather all information needed.

The idea would be as follows:

- any USB drive attached is automatically assigned a device node */dev/sdX* by the kernel
- if you loop over all device nodes */dev/sd[a-z]* (or rather, whichever are actually present under */dev/*) and call `udevadm info --query=all /dev/sdX` on each, you are able to determine which of these is a USB drive, because the output will have one line stating

```
E: ID_BUS=usb
```

- similarly, you will find output lines containing vendor and model, as in

```
E: ID_MODEL=Flash_Disk
< ... >
E: ID_VENDOR=Generic
```

Therefore, by parsing the output of `udevadm` using `grep` or similar, you will be able to gather all necessary information for you purposes.

Comment: Most answers require you to enter commands manually to find a devices device block. This answer will allow me to automate that in a script. Thank you.