# A script that tells me what device block an sd card in an sd card reader is attached to

Tags: linux, shell-script, sd-card

I have an sd card reader. It is a simple usb device with three different places to connect various types of sd card sizes into.

When I put an sd card in to it I can figure out that the sd card is available at `/dev/sdb` with commands like...

```
df -h

blkid -o list

fdisk -l
```

Is it possible to make a script that will automatically:

1. Tell me what device block the sd card is available at (e.g: `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb` etc..)
2. Unmount the sd card.

With `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` I have worked out the unique: ATTRS{idVendor}, ATTRS{idProduct} and ATTRS{serial} details for my sd card reader.

Can a script get the device block with these details?

Comment: For removable media you can mount automatically based on `UUID` and `PARTUUID` with `AutoFS`. Please have a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs

Comment: @binarysta Thank you but I don't want to mount the sd card. I want to know what device block the sd card is available at after it is inserted. I want a script to do that for me. I don't want to have to run any commands myself.

Comment: don't use sda or sdb ever, use what's already made available using uuid etc, in /dev/disk/by-*/ . Example of Q/A where I made an answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569603/external-usb-hdd-became-dev-sda-after-power-off-how-to-pin-it-to-dev-sdc/569616#569616

Comment: @A.B Cheers. But I don't like that approach because it requires me to know an identifier of the sd card in advance. I want a script that will work for any sd card that is inserted into this sd card reader.

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of googling I found [this helpful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550709/how-can-i-derive-block-device-information-using-the-output-of-lsusb).

Using `df -h` and `blkid -o list` I discovered the sd card was at `/dev/sdb`. Then I used `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb` to find the productID, VendorID and serial number of my sd card reader (usb device).

Now lets say I plug that sd card reader into another computer.. this script will loop through all `/dev/sdX` device blocks and report which one the sd card reader is attached to.

```
#!/bin/bash

# If ALL of these variables have values then you get "Success" below.
# If one or more of the variables do not contain a value (unset) or are null then you get "Failure" below.
# These are unique identifiers of the sd card reader
str_vendor="54jf"
str_product="775y"
str_serial="ID_SERIAL_SHORT=519S83946286"

for BLOCK in $(ls /dev | grep "^sd[a-z]$")
do
    echo "Device block " $BLOCK
    grep_vendor=$(udevadm info --query=all /dev/$BLOCK | grep $str_vendor)
    grep_product=$(udevadm info --query=all /dev/$BLOCK | grep $str_product)
    grep_serial=$(udevadm info --query=all /dev/$BLOCK | grep $str_serial)
    echo $grep_vendor
    echo $grep_product
    echo $grep_serial
    
    # From a comment to answer in above link... adding the colon [:] means to test if the variable is null OR unset
    # The udevadm commands result in the grep_* variables becoming NULL if the command returns nothing. (not sure?)
    # This is why the colon is needed. Note: Some reported that "This doesn't work in scripts where set -u is used"
    if [ -z ${grep_vendor:+x} ] || [ -z ${grep_product:+x} ] || [ -z ${grep_serial:+x} ]; then
        echo "Failure"
    else
        echo "Success"
    fi
    
done
```

How to check the status of the variables came from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829/1816113).

The reason for needing this functionality was so I can quickly partition and format any sd card connected to the sd card reader just by running a script.

Any feedback welcome!

Cheers,

Comment: take a look at dmesg when you insert a sd card

Comment: @ctac_ Yes I could do that but I don't want to have to do anything manually... just run a script and it does everything for me. I think it would be trickier to run a script on the dmesg output compared with polling all /dev/sdX devices.